# When does INSTALLED_APPS get imported on GAE if there is no warmup request?

Tags: django-nonrel, djangoappengine

djangoappengine.views.warmup does its job of loading all Django apps when GAE sends a warmup request. If GAE does not send a warmup request, either due to request spike or because warmup service is not enabled, then when does INSTALLED_APPS get imported? I see that djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application loads all INSTALLED_APPS, but djangoappengine.main.application does not.

The problem I'm having is that if there is no warmup request, then either that first loading request handler or subsequent request handler may need a nonrel-search model field which is not yet registered, because search was not imported via INSTALLED_APPS and thus autodiscover() did not yet run.

My settings MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES does have 'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware', so I would think that it could load that way without warmup, but it's not.

What is the solution to make sure everything is loaded before handling any requests?

Comment: I noticed that the official testapp, in addition to using autoload app and its middleware to expose multiple entry points to loading the search indexes, also explicitly calls autodiscover in urls.py, as shown here: https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp/blob/0c1245b381ab6a27c8ec3ff68f16ed84969b539f/urls.py

I guess that's how this issue is dealt with, although I'm not sure why these various entry points are not unified in a more coherent way. Perhaps someone can explain??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call search.autodiscover() in the site's urls.py, in addition to having autoload and search in INSTALLED_APPS, as well as autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

The reason is that while djangoappengine.views.warmup and djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application load INSTALLED_APPS and result in search.autodiscover() being called, djangoappengine.main.application does not does not do that. So if your GAE instance is fired up directly by a request, then the search indexes will not be registered. Therefore, search.autodiscover() in urls.py is necessary to register those indexes.